# About pallet's account

Tags: pallet

I use pallet account in my pallet.

```
pub const PALLET_ID: PalletId = PalletId(*b"abababab");
pub fn account_id() -> T::AccountId {
        PALLET_ID.into_account()
}
```

How can i get the pallet's account by polkadot.js app? Because i want to transfer some balance to the pallet's account.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can do it directly using polkadot.js but I can suggest you a couple of ways to obtain the account id you are looking for.

## The easy way

Just write a trivial Rust program that uses the Substrate API to get what you want:

```
use frame_support::PalletId;
use sp_runtime::{MultiSignature, traits::{AccountIdConversion, IdentifyAccount, Verify}};
type AccountId = <<MultiSignature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

let pallet_id = PalletId(*b"abababab");
let acc: AccountId = pallet_id.into_account();
println!("{}", acc.to_string());
```

## The manual way

This is if you are curious about understanding what is going on under to hood...

Given the pallet id: `"abababab"`, to manually reproduce what the `into_account` method is doing:

1. prepend the `"modl"` prefix to your pallet id

   ```
    "modlabababab" = (in hex) => 6d6f646c6162616261626162
   ```
2. zero pad the encoded byte array to 32 bytes

   ```
    6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
3. prepend the network id (e.g. 0x2a for Substrate network)

   ```
    2a6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
4. prepend the `"SS58PRE"` to the byte array computed in 3

   ```
    ("SS58PRE" = (in hex) => 53533538505245)
    => 535335385052452a6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
5. Compute the Blake2 hash of the byte array computed in 4

   ```
    $ echo 535335385052452a6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd -ps -r | b2sum --length 512
      70c39bed485b02f21d07be4de45946492f0177bb5663b3018fe5714fc8d014705c94ed4d7cae0b92ed9c141c298a2d72264fc87700f223dd94ccc6bf9202b025
   ```
6. append the first two bytes of the Blake2 hash (i.e. the "checksum") to the string computed in 3

   ```
    2a6d6f646c6162616261626162000000000000000000000000000000000000000070c3
   ```
7. convert to base 58

   ```
    $ echo 2a6d6f646c6162616261626162000000000000000000000000000000000000000070c3 | xxd -ps -r | base58
    5EYCAe5fiMgHBR7cyJUzU6YLj8uRjgHZrkt2VJxW5cjSHSYi
   ```

Your account id is `5EYCAe5fiMgHBR7cyJUzU6YLj8uRjgHZrkt2VJxW5cjSHSYi`

Note: if you don't have the `base58` tool installed you can always use an online tool such as [this](https://appdevtools.com/base58-encoder-decoder) (select "hex" input).

## Using Subkey

Once you have the byte array computed in point 3 of the "manual way" you can pass it directly to `subkey` tool

```
$ subkey inspect --public 6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Network ID/version: substrate
  Public key (hex):   0x6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  Account ID:         0x6d6f646c61626162616261620000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  SS58 Address:       5EYCAe5fiMgHBR7cyJUzU6YLj8uRjgHZrkt2VJxW5cjSHSYi
```

## Bonus

Shell script for the manual procedure

```
#!/bin/bash
pre=$(printf "modl"$1 | xxd -ps)
pre=$(printf "2a%-64s" $pre | sed 's/ /0/g')
to_hash=$(printf "53533538505245"$pre)
checksum=$(echo $to_hash | xxd -ps -r | b2sum --length 512 | cut -c 1-4)
echo $pre$checksum | xxd -ps -r | base58
```

Call it as:

```
   $ ./<thescriptname> abababab
   5EYCAe5fiMgHBR7cyJUzU6YLj8uRjgHZrkt2VJxW5cjSHSYi
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i have got it.